# Extracting XML snippets from text file using Python & Regex

Tags: python, regex, xml, python-3.x

I have a log file that contains multiple XML excerpts. They are mainly requests and response of a service call for a SOAP service. I want to extract these excerpts using regex and then parse them using some XML parsing library. Below is a sample part of the log file

```
DEBUG - GeronimoLog.debug(66) | GET MEX property org.apache.ode.bpel.myRoleSessionId = null
DEBUG - GeronimoLog.debug(66) | My-Role EPR not specified, SEP will not be used.
DEBUG - GeronimoLog.debug(66) | Axis2 sending message to http://localhost:8000/MagentoWS/services/InputsReceiver using MEX {PartnerRoleMex#hqejbhcnphrcdpwa4i059f [PID {ws.test}LogTestProc-558] calling org.apache.ode.bpel.epr.WSAEndpoint@4ced5499.receiveInputs(...)}
DEBUG - GeronimoLog.debug(66) | Message: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><receiveInputs xmlns="http://InputsReceiver.magento.ws">
                            <impl:input xmlns:impl="http://InputsReceiver.magento.ws">
                                <sku>24-MB03</sku>
                                <customer_id>2</customer_id>
                                <first_name>Micheal</first_name>
                                <last_name>Bowman</last_name>
                                <qty>1</qty>
                                <shipping_method>ground</shipping_method>
                                <street>117 Park Ave</street>
                                <city>Newark</city>
                                <postcode>07104</postcode>
                                <country_id>US</country_id>
                                <country>United State</country>
                                <region_id>41</region_id>
                                <region_code>NJ</region_code>
                                <telephone>+123456789</telephone>
                                <email>micheal@bowman.com</email>
                                <base_currency_code>USD</base_currency_code>
                                <cc_cid>123</cc_cid>
                                <cc_owner>Micheal Bowman</cc_owner>
                                <cc_number>5105105105105100</cc_number>
                                <cc_type>MasterCard</cc_type>
                                <cc_exp_year>2019</cc_exp_year>
                                <cc_exp_month>5</cc_exp_month>
                                <payment_method>checkmo</payment_method>
                                <companyEmail>ourcompany@ourcompany.com</companyEmail>
                                <subject>Order Email</subject>
                                <body>Email body</body>
                                <PayerID>Micheal123</PayerID>
                            </impl:input>
                        </receiveInputs></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
DEBUG - GeronimoLog.debug(66) | replyAsync mex=hqejbhcnphrcdpwa4i059f
DEBUG - GeronimoLog.debug(66) | Setting execution state on instance 177567
DEBUG - GeronimoLog.debug(66) | Sending stateful TO epr in message header using session null
DEBUG - GeronimoLog.debug(66) | Sending a message containing wsa endpoints in headers for session passing.
```

And I want to extract portion starting from `<?xml...` and ending at `</soapenv:Envelope>`. But I have failed to come up with a regex that would give me the desired result. Please note that there are multiple such XML excerpts in the file.

What I have tried so far and failed is the following `regex` patterns

```
Message: \<.*\>\n
Message: (<.*>\n)+
<\?xml.*Envelope?
Message: (<.*>(\n))+
```

Comment: try [this](https://regex101.com/r/Qpqglp/1)

Comment: matches the opening tag of first `xml` snippet and closing tag of last `xml` snippet

Comment: new link https://regex101.com/r/Qpqglp/2 with updated contents of file

Comment: `<\?xml(.*>\s)+` seems to work. Can check at https://regex101.com/r/Qpqglp/3. Please check if there might be any problems with this regex or I post it as an answer